# Handle API Response in .gzip with XML file inside

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, gzip

I'm trying to handle this API interaction with node.js (using express and request) but i'm having a lot of trouble dealing with the data.

Here's my current code:

```js
// Requirements
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");
const zlib = require("zlib");
const gunzip = require("gunzip-file");
const decompressResponse = require("decompress-response");
// Setting Up App
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("App Running");
});

// API Integration
let responseXML = "";
let bodyXML =
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RequestMensagemCB><login>14087809000107</login><senha>xxxx</senha><mId>1</mId></RequestMensagemCB>';

const options = {
  url: "http://webservice.newrastreamentoonline.com.br/",
  method: "POST",
  body: bodyXML
};

app.get("/onix", function(req, res) {
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    // body is the decompressed response body
    console.log(
      "server encoded the data as: " +
        (response.headers["content-encoding"] || "identity")
    );
    console.log("the decoded data is: " + body);
  })
    .on("data", function(data) {
      // decompressed data as it is received
      console.log("decoded chunk: " + data);
    })
    .on("response", function(response) {
      // unmodified http.IncomingMessage object
      response.on("data", function(data) {
        // compressed data as it is received
        console.log("received " + data.length + " bytes of compressed data");
      });
    });
});

// Server Listening

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Server Online Listening to port 3000");
});
```

This is the console.log response i get:

[image]

Using postman i can reach the XML through the following route:

I first make the post request with the XML needed to validate the API Access, then i send and download the response giving it the extension of .gz and inside the .gz there's a compressed version of the file that when opened shows the XML response:

[image]

This is my first time working with an API that returns the data in .gz that way. I've tried piping the data using zLib and now was thinking on the following route: download the response in .gz, decompress the resulting file, then opening it to reach the XML. I imagine there's a better way of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

I Could fix the code through another approach.

I've added 2 more params for the const options:

```js
const options = {
  url: "http://webservice.newrastreamentoonline.com.br/",
  method: "POST",
  body: bodyXML,
  headers: {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
  },
  encoding: null,
  gzip: true
};
```

The key value is the following: `encoding: null,` , that way the stream comes without corruption.

Then i've been able to print out the XML response. Using xml2json NPM i've been able to convert it on a JSON object, and now i'll work normally with the data.